# Intermittent error of "The requested content does not exist" for Static Website in Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I've got a react app that is hosted in an Azure storage account with static website enabled, however, the page sometimes displays "The requested content does not exist." on some loads of the page.
[image]

It's very intermittent, it works about 80% of the time.

As for the configuration, it is set up to load the `index.html` page for the index document and also the error document.

[image: configuration]

Is there a fix to this problem?

Here's some extra details around the storage account setup:

-Location: North Europe

-Performance/Access tier: Standard/Hot

-Replication: Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)

-Account Kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

***Update***

I've done a little more digging around and figured out that one of the IP addresses in the DNS entry does not go anywhere.

Doing a `nslookup` on the entry gives the following:

```
Name:    web.db1prdstrz01a.store.core.windows.net
Addresses:  52.245.40.97
          52.239.137.33
          52.239.195.1
```

If I curl each of these IPs with the host header I get the following responses:

```
curl --insecure -I --header 'Host: xxx.z16.web.core.windows.net' 'https://52.239.137.33'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

```
curl --insecure -I --header 'Host: xxx.z16.web.core.windows.net' 'https://52.239.195.1'

HTTP/1.1 404 The requested content does not exist.
Server: Windows-Azure-Web/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: ba831141-c01e-009d-5196-ddc969000000
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2020 09:09:43 GMT
Connection: close
```

```
curl --insecure -I --header 'Host: xxx.z16.web.core.windows.net' 'https://52.245.40.97'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

So it seems that the problem originates from the DNS entry, I've tried to re-create the storage accounts and still get the same IPs, How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you visit the site? if you visit it via `https://yourAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$web/index.html`, then you need to set the container $web as public.

Comment: It's using the url with the `.z00` in it (https://yourAccount.z16.web.core.windows.net/) so not the direct container url. From reading it says that if you use that one it doesn't care about any of the permissions set on the container?

Comment: You're right. If using the url like `yourAccount.z16.web.core.windows.net`, then it would work regardless of the container is public or private. I suggest you'd better submit a support ticket to MS for the issue.

Comment: @IvanYang seems to raise a support ticket Azure wants to charge me $100/mo for their service not working?

Comment: Hi Kevin, if it's just a simple project, can you share it with me? I can take a try at my side, if I can repro, I can help you raise a ticket:).

Comment: It's just a static html file in a storage account ($web) that has static website hosting enabled, it's nothing special. Oddly I created another one just to see if it was just that instance and that one has the same problem too.

Comment: Can you please let me know the region of storage account v2? My static site url is account.z22.web.core.windows.net, not sure if it's the related region issues.

Comment: It's in North Europe, I've also updated the question with some other details

Comment: Hi Kevin, I followed your step / configuration, but still cannot repro the issue. Here is a suggestion. I'm not sure if the issue is related to the index.html itself. To check this, you can create a simple 404.html with content `<h1>error page 404</h1>`, and upload it to the $web container; Then for "Error document path", please change it to 404.html. Then if visit the site, it displays the 404.html page, it should be the issue with the index.html.

Comment: @IvanYang uploaded a `404.html` page and still getting the same error message. This morning it seems to very consistent by hitting the root page `/` it's always returning back the error message.

Comment: @IvanYang literally had to disable static websites and re-enable it on the site to get it to work today.

Comment: Weirdly I now get 2 URLs a Primary and Secondary URL, whereas it use to only have a Primary. I feel Azure has been pulling the carpet from under me... let's see if this works any better...

Comment: You only had a primary url previously? That's too weird, we always have 2 urls for Primary and secondary.

Comment: @IvanYang seems it's a DNS related issue, see my latest update.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the update, it is out of my knowledge, sorry. I suggest you'd better raise a new issue about this(seems that people here like to work on the new issues, not the old one), and delete this post.